# haskell: recursive function that return the char in a tuple list with certain condition(compare)

Tags: python, haskell

I'm learning recursive function in haskell that confused with such conditon:

I got a tuple list here:

```
[(0.5,'!'),(1,'*'),(1.5,'#')]
```

What I want to do is input a number n and compare with fist number in each tuple of the list

so suppose n=0.1, when it compared 0.5 and find it is smaller than 0.5, it will return char '!'

suppose n=0.7, which is > 0.5 and keep comparing, find that it < 1, then it will return char '*'

and after compare the whole list and find d is still bigger than the last one, it will just return char 'n'

I've been work with such condition lots of time,but still cannot get to this, here is my code:

```
find :: Double -> [(Double,Char)] -> Char
find d [] = ' '
find d xs
    | d <= Double(xs[0]) = xs[0]
    | d > Double(xs[0]) = find d tail(xs)
```

please use recursion!

Comment: I don't think `tail(xs)` does what you think it does.

Comment: @immibis as I expected it should return the list without the first tuple, so you mean this will not work in a list with tuple?? And what tail give in this code?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `tail(xs)` is the same as `tail (xs)`, so in this context `find d tail(xs)` is the same as `find d tail xs` which "passes three arguments" to `find`.

Comment: You probably can't / don't want to change the exercise requirement, but note that returning `'n'` as the error value for "not found" is quite unidiomatic in Haskell. This is because if we get `'n'` back we don't know whether it was found and it was `'n'` or it was not found. A more standard approach would be to return a `Maybe Char` instead of a plain `Char`.

Comment: @chi what do you mean a maybr char？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tuple](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_and_tuples) is different from array in Haskell

```
find :: Double -> [(Double,Char)] -> Char
find d [] = ' '
find d (x:xs)
    | d <= fst x = snd x
    | otherwise = find d xs
```

Comment: I try this, and it still said "Parse error in pattern:"

Comment: I am sorry I just missed `()`.

Comment: That works, do you have any resources like website that give more example on list+tuple ?

Comment: List and tuple are the most commonly used data structures in Haskell, there are tons of great resources you can refer to such as: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out

Comment: And *list* is also very, very different from *array*.